# How to fetch the page source of the website which i can see by clicking "View page source" in Google Chrome using python requests

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I need to get html page source of the "https://youtube.com". The one I can view by clicking "view page source" in Chrome. How can I get this html in python?

Comment: You're looking for an HTTP client.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+http+request

Comment: Yeah, but how can I get the page source which I get when typing 'view-source:https://www.youtube.com/' in chrome.

Comment: By sending an HTTP request.  Learn what HTTP is.